# [Symfony2.8][FOSUserBundle] CSRF Token invalid, no session file written with beta prod deployment

Tags: php, symfony, session, fosuserbundle

*I've first posted my issue [on a french forum](https://openclassrooms.com/forum/sujet/symfony2-8-fosub-jeton-csrf-invalide-en-prod), but i thought it'd also be a good idea to seek for help here.*
I think i'll go straight to the point. I've deployed a beta on a server for a site i worked on locally in dev environment. I used Capifony and DoctrineMigrations. I'm using FOSUserBundle with a custom UserBundle inheriting FOSUB. Some fields are added to the User class, etc. Don't worry i didn't override the main views and there's no {{ form_rest(form) }} missing or anything like that.

Everything works locally, but as you can expect, on the server it's not the same. The app/logs/prod.log returns nothing, i tried to put a level: debug into Monolog config (app/config/config_prod.yml) but it'd changed nothing.

Part of app/config/config.yml regarding sessions :

```
    session:
        handler_id:  session.handler.native_file
        save_path: "%kernel.root_dir%/sessions/"
```

*[TL;DR]* There's no sessions files on the server about this site neither in app/sessions nor anywhere else. I assume the issue with CSRF token being invalid comes from the sessions issue.

No way there's a permission rights issue, app/sessions is chmoded 777 (same as app/logs and app/cache) with the right chown. The web/config.php returns no issue with the configuration. I don't know how to find the cause of this issue as it totally works locally and you can't debug on a prod environment if there's nothing in the log... Any idea ?

Comment: You might create a small controller test script which creates a file in the sessions directory and see if it throws any errors. No logs and no sessions means that the app is unable to create files in the filesystem, be it a permissions or path configuration or any other issue.

Comment: @Karolis : I just did with a try / catch. It displays the response i put in try after the fopen w+, so it said it worked, but it doesn't. No file is created on the server in app/sessions, while locally it works. fopen returns false apparently, but nothing more unfortunately. I guess i need to use something else to get more info.

Comment: @Karolis : Can't edit after 5 minutes. But i just got the error using error_get_last(), and it's indeed related to permissions... :   

`failed to open stream: Permission denied [file]`  

I dunno why since it's 777 and owned by the supposed right user/group. Edit : Okay... It was 777 on the symlink, the real dir was 755. I feel... dumb. Problem solved i guess.

Comment: Glad you have worked this out :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, it was indeed an issue with permissions. The issue was related to Capifony. The shared_children are symlinks. And when you chmod a symlink, it doesn't chmod anything. So here for instance the shared/app/sessions directory was still in 755 which wasn't enough.

If you've a similar issue. Be sure the permissions for the shared_children in your Cap project directory / shared all well set.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem and finally the solution was in the `php.ini` file

the variable `post_max_size` was equal to `100Mo` in production mode which was not enough in order to post the token, the pseudo and password.

I get stuck 3 days with this problem xD